# Modifying every DateTime instance in Model (Server Time to Client Time)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there way to modify every DateTime instance that gets from controller to view?

I have datetime saved on server in UTC timezone. But in browser I need to show date in client timezone.
So every time I have to manually convert datetime in clients timezone:

```
model.DateCreated = ConvertToClientTimeZone(model.DateCreated)
```

This is not comfortable. So i'm asking about possible way to do this conversion automatically?

Comment: How are you displaying the dates within the view? (This feels like something the view should be doing rather than changing the model.)

Comment: I'm displaying dates as usual, by formatting it into string: <b>@Model.DateCreated.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")</b>

Comment: Right - I would put the `ConvertToClientTimeZone` there rather than in the model. After all, you're only changing how the data is *presented*.

Comment: The problem comes when I forget to add ConvertToClientTimeZone in the view.

Comment: So make sure you don't do that, and make sure you have testing which covers that. Changing the *model* is not the right approach, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use view models you can also put time zone transformation logic inside mapping functionality that converts your domain models into view models.

I.e. if you are using AutoMapper I think it is possible to configure AutoMapper so that when mapping dates it automatically does a conversion from UTC (in DB) to client time zone. That way you reduce the possibility to forget to call a transformation helper function and show the user a bad DateTime.

Don't forget that you also must do a transformation from DateTimes that are coming from the client to DB (from view models to domain models).

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom HTML helper:

```
public static IHtmlString FormatDate(this HtmlHelper html, DateTime date)
{
    string result = ... format the date however you like
    return new HtmlString(result);
}
```

and then in the view:

```
@Html.FormatDate(model.DateCreated)
```

Comment: The problem comes when I forget to add @Html.FormatDate in the view.

Comment: Another possibility is to use a view model and have the date already formatted on your view model. That's the most correct way. If you are not using view models and directly passing your domain entities to your views, you should not forget to call the helper.